# Probabilities and Certainties on the Monkey Axis: Yet more about those monkey typists

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, probability, infinity, thought-experiment

I was reading with some interest the answers and comments to [this question about that familiar, weird and somewhat inhumane infinite-monkey experiment](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/103909/why-would-infinite-monkeys-not-produce-the-works-of-shakespeare) which, somehow, is still generating fresh and interesting discussions, among which was @OverLordGoldDragon's astute comment that, actually, given an infinite amount of time, it would really only take one monkey to perform the feat.

It is such a good comment, in fact, that it sparks further thought: If only dimension of infinity is required to ensure that all events occurring with nonzero probability *do*, in fact, *almost surely occur*, then that dimension could just as easily be on the monkey axis rather than the time axis.

That is, given infinite monkeys, we might assume that, as soon as the starting gun is fired (or however the designated official might normally commence such experiments), one monkey among them will begin typing *All's Well That Ends Well* straightaway and won't stop until he's typed the last character of *The Winter's Tale*.

Then this would imply that the time it would take is limited only by that particular monkey's typing speed. It's likely that I'm rehashing material that philosophy settled ages ago, but I wasn't able to find a discussion on these particulars—that is, until someone with rare tact and kindness pointed out [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem), which pretty much covers all these ideas in a more succinct and less stream-of-consciousness way, and comprises, in my frame of reference, a very good example of time flowing in the direction of more complete (yet always still incomplete) knowledge.

So then, continuing along that line, with infinite monkeys, isn't there some subset of monkeys that are all typing the same thing, albeit at different speeds? And wouldn't we also expect that all possible monkey-typing speeds are attained—and, by the way, don't these thought experiments conjure the strangest mental imagery!—from the very slowest possible monkey-typing speed (which would be the monkey's adult lifespan divided by the number of characters) to the very fastest (whatever that is; perhaps it's nothing more than a narcissistic human pride that forbids any supposition that a monkey could surpass Barbara Blackburn's record of 212 wpm, although again, with infinite monkeys, we can expect there will be some heroes).

It is difficult to search for the number of alphanumeric characters that appear in Shakespeare's plays without getting buried in irrelevant statistics such as that there are "60 characters in *Henry VI, Part II*." So I downloaded the theatrical corpus of Shakespeare plays from this [Weaton College repository](https://digitalrepository.wheatoncollege.edu/items/ebcd39e3-366c-4a34-a662-189403100799) and performed a `wc -m` on them, which returned a total character count of 5,577,875.

Then, anticipating too late the arithmetic operation that is to come, I realize my error and backtrack to find that there are `wc -w` = 929,162 *words* contained in the corpus, which is probably searchable, and at 212 words per minute comes in at a bit under an hour and a quarter.

Which seems impressive.

Is that really all the time it would take? Could it take even less time somehow? How close to instantaneous could it get? Or is my logic fundamentally flawed?

Comment: i found a new [phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely)

Comment: It must have been you who mentioned these terms in the other post, and I was meaning to look the phrases up to see what they mean precisely ... and wow, it looks like it's all about that distinction between certainty and inevitability, maybe. Just that some set of events could be non-empty and yet still occur with probability 0 is blowing my mind right now. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: i didn't post on the other thread. there's a wikipage for the infinte monkey theorem, which idk anyone has read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem

Comment: I guess I should have read that before adding my own chatter to the totality of more dignified and enlightened discussions on the subject.

Comment: Hm. It looks like that Wikipedia article already covers the points I was trying to make, only it does so more succinctly. I wonder if that means I should delete this one? (It's my first post, if that wasn't already obvious.)

Comment: yeah. dignity is difficult ha don't feel awkward just be enlightening :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149213/discussion-between-brandon-burt-and-prof-post).

Comment: BTW, we are assuming that the monkeys are actually typing. If there are infinite ways in which monkeys could ignore a typewriter, then the complete works might not get written.

Comment: Mental puzzles are not philosophy.

Comment: Having it "only" take some small finite amount of time is rather irrelevant, given that you've already included infinity. Infinite monkeys times finite time is infinity. One monkey times infinite time is infinity. Infinite monkeys times infinite time is infinity. It's all just different ways to get to the same result (well, you technically have countable and uncountable infinities there, but that's a maths detail that probably wouldn't be of consequence to most people).

Comment: It could be quite a bit lower, as the monkeys can hit copy + paste for any duplicate sentences/words. It could probbaly be near instant if a monkey can get a macro to randomely select keys for it. As for the "amost surely" point, it's basically akin to: Imagine You throw a dart at the Real Number Line, The probability that you hit a natural number is 0, but that doesn't mean it's impossible. Same thing here with the monkey's it really depends on the contraints of the problem.

Comment: The fundamental flaw in these (silly) exercises is to presume that some monkey might eventually be capable of typing the complete works of Shakespeare if we just make the time/monkey quantity infinite.  Monkeys can't type.  They cannot read English.  They wouldn't even try to type.  An infinite amount of monkeys, with an infinite amount of typewriters, given an infinite amount of time, would produce an infinite amount of busted parts.  That's it.  Garbage in, garbage out.